# Node affinity ignored for a node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-statefulset

I have 3 nodes, each of them labeled like following:

- node-0 -> mongo-volume=volume-0
- node-1 -> mongo-volume=volume-1
- node-2 -> mongo-volume=volume-2

I'm looking for a way to schedule the replicas of a statefulset on a special node.

I first used the hard way with requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution and everything works well.

Then I wanted to test the soft way by using preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.

I first tell to my statefulset to have a preference for the node having the label **volume-0**, no problems the pods were all deployed on the **node-0**.

Then I changed the preference for the node having the label **volume-1**. And there is my problem, the pods were deployed on the **node-0** and **node-2** but node on the **node-1**.

I did the same with the label volume-2 and it works well again, the pods were all deployed on the **node-2**.

Node Affinity configuration:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 100
      preference:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: mongo-volume
          operator: In
          values:
          - volume-1
```

When I looked for the resource usage of the nodes, I noticed that the node-1 had a bit more load than the others. Could it explain why the sheduler refuses to deploy the pods on this node ?

```
NAME    CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
node-0   63m          6%     795Mi           41%
node-1   116m         11%    978Mi           51%
node-2   78m          7%     752Mi           39%
```

I'm wondering why it works for the node-0 and the node-2 but not for the node-1. And if there is a possible way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinity policy is **prefer** to run on this node, not **select directly** the node.

The weight of your affinity is the priority of your affinity policies. For example:

```sh
podAntiAffinity:
  preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
  - weight: 100
    podAffinityTerm:
      labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: k1
          operator: In
          values:
          - "v1"
      topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  - weight: 30
    podAffinityTerm:
      labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: k2
          operator: In
          values:
          - "v2"
      topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

[K8s scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/) doc says:

> kube-scheduler selects a node for the pod in a 2-step operation:
>
> 1. Filtering
> 2. Scoring
>
> The filtering step finds the set of Nodes where it’s feasible to schedule the Pod. For example, the PodFitsResources filter checks whether a candidate Node has enough available resource to meet a Pod’s specific resource requests. After this step, the node list contains any suitable Nodes; often, there will be more than one. If the list is empty, that Pod isn’t (yet) schedulable.
>
> In the scoring step, the scheduler ranks the remaining nodes to choose the most suitable Pod placement. The scheduler assigns a score to each Node that survived filtering, basing this score on the active scoring rules.
>
> Finally, kube-scheduler assigns the Pod to the Node with the highest ranking. If there is more than one node with equal scores, kube-scheduler selects one of these at random

Affinity is part of the consideration but not all.